# MVC 4 Razor image mouse over show larger image

Tags: jquery, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Does anyone know of a way to add some JQuery that will allow a user to hover over an UNKNOWN id created dynamically in a foreach loop in Razor? I need to grab the id when the image is moused over or hovered and perform a .show(); for that image. I have it working on other pages with one image but can't figure out what to do for many images with unknown id's.

here is the image div that has both images. The full image displays overtop the smaller one and goes away on mouse out or no hover.

```
<div class="listEntriesPhoto" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
            <img id="EntriesDiagramLeft-@item.ImageName" src='~/documents/@item.ImageName' alt="repeating default photo of woman" />

            <!--This is for image hover for larger picture-->
            <div id="EntriesFullDiagramLeft-@item.ImageName" style="display:none;" >
                <img id="EntriesfullImageLeft-@item.ImageName" src='~/documents/@item.ImageName' alt="Submitted image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be great and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the class "listEntriesPhoto" your root div element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
  var photoList = $(".listEntryPhoto").find("img");
  .each(photoList, function(){
          var image = $(this);
          // Whatever code you used for one image goes here
          // using the image variable
    };
```

Comment: Hi Jared! I finally have had time to respond as I was on a tight deadline originally and then forgot. anyway, I gave you the credit for the answer because I ended up piecing what you posted and what I already had and it works beautifully! here is the code:

Comment: here is the code:             $(".DiagramLeft").mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).next(".FullDiagramLeft").show('normal');
            });
            $(".FullDiagramLeft").mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).hide('normal');
            });